# is there a way to generate positive random numbers with fixed mean and SD, and sd > mean?

Tags: r, random, simulation

I want to generat a veusing R.
Is there a way to generate a sequence of *POSITIVE* numbers that satisfy specific constraints

- a mean of 13,
- a standard deviation of 30.96 , and
- a sample size of 6.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but the sequence will be correlated because of the constraints you impose.  Is that what you want?  Here's one way, in brief.  Generate four numbers, in any way you want.  Then set up a system of simultaneous equations for the two remaining numbers that will give you the mean and standard deviation you want.  Not all choices of the first four numbers will lead to solutions for the last two.  That's an answer to the question you asked, but I'm not convinced it's the question you *meant* to ask.

Comment: Note that a *random sample* drawn from a population with mean 13 and sd 30.96 will almost certainly **not** have a sample mean of 13 and a sample SD of 30.96.  Also, because your SD is greater than your mean and you restrict yourself to positive numbers, both your population and sample will be skewed.

Comment: `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13 * 6]` has a sample standard deviation of ~31.84, and is the max variance given your other constraints, so it's possible.  but given that it's only just larger than the variance you've requested implies that the values are from a heavy tailed distribution

Comment: @SamMason: that’s a good observation, but zero is not a positive number. (Though it is non-negative.) And the sample clearly isn’t random!

Comment: @Limey Perhaps the definition of positive varies from place to place or field to field. My undergrad and grad curricula both defined positive as >= 0, and used the phrase strictly positive for > 0.

Comment: Your question seems ambiguous to me. Are you asking for 6 random numbers from a population with the specified mean and standard deviation, or for a sample of size 6 having those values as the average (sample mean) and s (sample standard deviation)? In other words, are you specifying distributional parameters or the parameter estimates based on data?

Answer (score 2):

Another option (after echoing all the concerns about this being an XY problem):

We can transform `n` samples of practically *any* continuous distribution by finding a pair of scale and translation parameters that satisfies the desired constraints.

```
f <- function(n, mu, sigma) {
  x <- rnorm(n) # substitute any continuous distribution here
  fn <- function(par) {
    y <- exp(x*par[2] + par[1])
    log(abs(mean(y) - mu) + abs(sd(y) - sigma))
  }
  
  with(optim(c(0, 0), fn), exp(x*par[2] + par[1]))
}

# example usage
f(6L, 13, 30.96)
#> [1] 2.569263e-09 1.912637e-06 9.521086e-05 4.023787e-01 7.618698e+01 1.410541e+00

# take 20 sets of samples
m <- matrix(NA, 20, 8)

for (i in 1:nrow(m)) {
  m[i, 1:6] <- sort(f(6L, 13, 30.96))
  m[i, 7] <- mean(m[i, 1:6]) - 13 # difference from desired mean
  m[i, 8] <- sd(m[i, 1:6]) - 30.96 # difference from desired SD
}

m
#>                [,1]          [,2]         [,3]         [,4]      [,5]     [,6]          [,7]          [,8]
#>  [1,]  2.373175e-12  5.239577e-08 1.612212e-07 9.033024e-01 0.9063398 76.19036 -7.105427e-15 -1.776357e-14
#>  [2,]  1.185131e-17  2.420683e-12 1.967461e-11 1.613739e-03 1.8189977 76.17939 -7.105427e-15  3.552714e-15
#>  [3,]  4.178030e-03  6.449223e-03 3.329587e-02 7.889274e-02 1.6949839 76.18220  1.776357e-15  0.000000e+00
#>  [4,]  1.134263e-19  8.582391e-13 3.675582e-12 7.909737e-06 1.8206428 76.17935 -1.776357e-15 -3.552714e-15
#>  [5,]  3.875063e-11  5.453168e-06 1.005380e-05 7.971751e-02 1.7390532 76.18121 -3.552714e-15  0.000000e+00
#>  [6,]  2.057442e-10  1.395120e-04 2.825930e-03 8.257653e-01 0.9809560 76.19031  1.065814e-14  0.000000e+00
#>  [7,]  3.281160e-02  3.939408e-02 4.617334e-02 6.313399e-01 1.0591873 76.19109 -1.776357e-15 -1.776357e-14
#>  [8,]  1.652719e-08  1.700647e-08 2.909621e-05 1.366993e-02 1.8066190 76.17968 -1.065814e-14 -1.065814e-14
#>  [9,]  3.231989e-18  1.103402e-08 4.891128e-08 2.246015e-01 1.5912433 76.18416  1.776357e-15  0.000000e+00
#> [10,]  2.147959e-25  1.412579e-21 4.929303e-16 7.013902e-04 1.8199323 76.17937  0.000000e+00 -5.684342e-14
#> [11,]  8.239083e-08  1.516883e-05 4.268010e-01 6.580114e-01 0.7215226 76.19365  1.065814e-14  3.552714e-15
#> [12,]  8.837010e-05  7.983109e-04 3.712888e-03 9.311085e-03 1.8064017 76.17969  0.000000e+00 -7.105427e-15
#> [13,] 3.586152e-178 2.149918e-134 1.681243e-56 2.681863e-09 1.8206509 76.17935 -5.329071e-15 -9.592327e-14
#> [14,]  5.860182e-07  1.645025e-05 1.057840e-03 3.878328e-02 1.7798381 76.18030 -1.776357e-15 -3.552714e-15
#> [15,]  2.363474e-05  1.090204e-03 3.533081e-03 2.924378e-01 1.5174856 76.18543  0.000000e+00  1.421085e-14
#> [16,]  1.666746e-03  6.105670e-02 1.966066e-01 6.731973e-01 0.8746421 76.19283  1.776357e-15  0.000000e+00
#> [17,]  1.633101e-06  5.641356e-05 2.427083e-02 9.874914e-02 1.6947355 76.18219 -1.598721e-14 -7.105427e-15
#> [18,]  2.124617e-72  2.143486e-68 9.930707e-68 1.367184e-08 1.8206509 76.17935  2.842171e-14 -1.776357e-14
#> [19,]  5.846315e-19  1.528350e-06 2.030263e-06 7.959439e-04 1.8198318 76.17937 -1.776357e-15 -1.776357e-14
#> [20,]  5.630657e-03  1.462770e-01 2.914364e-01 6.119128e-01 0.7504916 76.19425  1.776357e-15  0.000000e+00
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @SamMason's comment, here is an empirical solution.  Though I am concerned that providing OP with an answer may actually do them a disservice, since I suspect this may well be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

First, establish if it is possible to construct a set of six numbers that satisfy OP's constraints:

```
f <- function(x) {
  y <- c(rep(x, 5), 6*13 - 5*x)
  sd(y) - 30.96
}

uniroot(f, c(0, 1))$root
[1] 0.3606329

> y
[1]  0.3606329  0.3606329  0.3606329  0.3606329  0.3606329 76.1968355
> mean(y)
[1] 13
> sd(y)
[1] 30.96
```

So, yes, it is possible to construct a set of six numbers that meets OP's constraints.  Now introduce a (small) degree of variation into the first five elements of the sample, fix the sixth to satisfy the mean constraint and calculate the sample SD.  If the SD isn't "close enough" to the target, throw the sample away and try again.  Impose an upper limit to the number of tries to prevent infinite looping.

```
# For reproducibility
set.seed(1234)

f1 <- function(sd) {
  y <- rnorm(5, mean=0.3606329, sd=sd)
  y[6] <- 6*13 - sum(y)
  y
}

findIt <- function(sd, epsilon=0.001, maxIter=1000) {
  iteration <- 0
  found <- FALSE
  while(!found) {
    z <- f1(sd)
    if (abs(sd(z) - 30.96) < epsilon) {
      found <- TRUE
      return(z)
    }
    iteration <- iteration + 1
    if (iteration == maxIter) {
      warning(paste0("No solution found after ", maxIter, " iterations"))
      return(NA)
    }
  }
}

z <- findIt(0.2)
> z
[1]  0.44505164  0.66907765  0.47566925  0.09247431  0.12141987 76.19630728
> mean(z)
[1] 13
> sd(z)
[1] 30.96053
```

Note that `findIt()` is sloppy in that it assumes that the SD is "small enough" that all generated values are positive.

This procedure generates a sample that is "random" in the sense that five of the values are iid N(0.3606329, sigma * sigma) and the fifth is (highly) correlated with the sum of the other five.  The joint distribution of all six values in the sample is not obvious to me.

I can't imagine a scenario in which this is a sensible thing to do.

Comment: yup, agreed about the XY problem comment.  note that an IID draw from a half-Cauchy distribution looks like it could give values similar to this.  e.g. I just got a draw of `0.7085618 114.7796090   1.2103768   0.7435597   1.6212601   0.1917702` from `abs(rcauchy(6))`